# How to get ground acceleration with compass&& acceleration sensor in android?

Tags: android, sensors

I want to get the acceleration of three direction(North,South,Sky) with the data from TYPE_ACCELEROMETER and TYPE_ORIENTATION(or Compass). What should I do to calculate?

Comment: https://github.com/hoananguyen/dsensor

Comment: @HoanNguyen I do not think it could solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get acceleration in World coordinate with `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` and `TYPE_ORIENTATION`. You need `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` and one of `TYPE_GRAVITY` or `TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` or `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`. I am pretty sure that the depreciated `TYPE_ORIENTATION` also use one of the three above.

Comment: So how can I get the acceleration of three direction? Could you please show me your code?

Comment: Just use my library and in your code call DSensorManager.startDSensor with dSensor type parameter DSensor.TYPE_WORLD_ACCELEROMETER

Comment: Ok, I will have a try. Thanks.

Comment: The DSensorManager.startDSensor return an integer you should bit AND this value with TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD if it is not zero then it is not possible to calculate the magnetic field in world coordinate. You can run my sample apps to see if your device has TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD